# Running node-js code inside angular2 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

How can i run this code from angular2 app  component?

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");

var img = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/custombionicle/images/a/ae/Kitten_with_gun_final.png";

request(img).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.png'));
```

Comment: You can't, your AngularJS code will be executed client side, NodeJS is server side.

Comment: is there a way to implement this using angular2?

Comment: There is no way to write files to the user disk using client side javascript (for obvious security reasons), as suggested by Razvan Alex, you can write this code in your backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, node.js is the backend part of the website and angular the frontend, you can't mix them together. What you can do instead is to run the pice of code on the backend and if there's some data you need it on the client side, to send it to the client ;)